# Is there a cleaner way of doing this if statement?

Tags: java, if-statement, charat

```
if(input.charAt(i) == '0' || input.charAt(i) == '1' || input.charAt(i) == '2') {
}
```

Is there a way to condense this if condition, or no?

Comment: Create an array, check if it contains the value :/

Comment: A switch statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could check if the character matches any index in a common `String`. Like,

```
if ("012".indexOf(input.charAt(i)) > -1) {

}
```

Comment: @Steven You would have to benchmark it, and this is highly unlikely to be critical path in a real application. I doubt it's measurable. Just like using a `switch(input.charAt(i)) { case '0': case '1': case '2': /* code */ }` is probably exactly the same as OP's post.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe a little more readable (in java 9+)

```
if (Set.of('0', '1', '2').contains(input.charAt(i))) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make it *shorter* by assigning the character lookup result in a variable (but still three equality checks).

```
char c = input.charAt(i);
if(c == '0' || c == '1' || c == '2') {
}
```

You can look at the other answers like creating a Set/Array and doing the *contains* check if the number of equality checks will increase in the future. IMO, three checks should be fine to be written as is.